# Login accepts password with any extra characters appended

Tags: encryption, hash, authentication, passwords

I don't know whether this is actually a problem or not. I did tell the IT administrators but I got no reply and nothing was done.

At my university, everyone has a logon account. I discovered that it would accept my password if I added a random string after it.

So if my password was

```
password
```

It accepts

```
password123
passwordhvgFghvjej36277
```

And so on. It does not accept anything like

```
passwor
133password
```

It only works if the password is correct and begin the phrase.

Is this a big problem?
Surely if they are hashing the passwords, adding an extra character will change the hash?

Answer (score 0):

This will happen if they cut off the password after a certain maximum length. Not really good practice, but unfortunately not uncommon.

So what gets hashed (hopefully they do hash!) is just a fixed-length prefix of what you entered.

Of course, it could also mean that they just store a fixed-length truncated clear-text password. That would be terrible.

Comment: Oh I see, that would make sense because they generate passwords for everyone. Although I feel like I may be able to change may password with a different length

Comment: Yes, you can change your password to 25 characters, but only the first eight (for example) will matter.

Comment: Sounds like it could be [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_(C)#Traditional_DES-based_scheme) ancient scheme.

Comment: Especially if the limit is exactly about 8 characters (would be interesting to check), this hints to the DES algorithm. This would be a real security risk, such hashes can be brute-forced within a fraction of a second. Even more, they are often salted only with [2 characters](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php).